# ng-bootstrap ngbdropdown placement not working with angular 4.3.5

Tags: ng-bootstrap

The placement does not work for "top-right". Just goes to the default.

My packages:

"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
   "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",

```
<div ngbDropdown placement="top-right" class="d-inline-block">
                <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" id="dropdownBasic2" ngbDropdownToggle>Auto Fill Queue From
                    Library
                </button>
                <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic2">
                    <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="rebuild(3)">4 More Days</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="rebuild(3)">3 More Days</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="rebuild(2)">2 More Days</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="rebuild(1)">Through Tomorrow</button>
                    <button class="dropdown-item" (click)="rebuild(0)">Rest of Today</button>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `placement` option for [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) [dropdowns](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples) was added only in [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io) `1.0.0-beta.2` so you need to update your version of [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io). More info can be found in the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md).

With the version updated it works perfectly fine, you can verify it here: http://plnkr.co/edit/jZIt2YDWdqUOxCESig41?p=preview.

Comment: The plunkr only shows "loading...". The placement does not work for me inside a premiere pro panel (cef with node), using ngb v6.0.2 with bootstrap v4.4.1 in an angular v9.0.1 environment.